# Conjectures inspired in the context of Casas-Alvero conjecture, via the logarithmic derivative of derivatives of a polynomial

Tags: nt.number-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials

In the post (cross-posted in Mathematics Stack Exchange with identificator MSE [**4244256**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4244256/conjectures-inspired-in-the-context-of-casas-alvero-conjecture-via-the-logarith) and same title) we assume that $P(x)=a_0+a_{1}x+\ldots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n}x^n$ is a polynomial of degree $1<\deg(P)=d=n$ defined over a field $K$ of characteristic zero. We denote its derivatives as $P^{(i)}(x)$ (writting $P^{(0)}(x)=P(x)$), and $a_n$ denotes the leading coefficient of $P(x)$.

I've stated two conjectures (as speculations from the fact) inspired in that I've proven inductively that each polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $1<\deg(p)$ (and with corresponding $a_n\neq 0$) satisfies $$p(x)=a_n\cdot\left(\frac{n-l}{\frac{d}{dx}\log p^{(l)}(x)} \right)^n\tag{1}$$
for each integer $l$ with $0\leq l<n-1$.

**Conjecture 1.** *Let* $P(x)$ *a polynomial of degree* $1<n$, *thus we assume* $P^{(n)}(0)\neq 0$. *If the equation* $$P(x)=\frac{P^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\cdot\left(\frac{n-l}{\frac{d}{dx}\log P^{(l)}(x)} \right)^n$$ *holds for each integer* $0\leq l<n-1$, *then* $P(x)$ *has the form* $$P(x)=\frac{P^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\cdot(x-\alpha)^n$$ *for some element* $\alpha\in K$.

I know the statement of the called Casas-Alvero conjecture from Wikipedia [*Casas-Alvero conjecture*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casas-Alvero_conjecture). I've speculated (while I don't know if this has a good mathematical content, or if these ideas are in the literature in some way more or less explicit) if from previous simple idea one can to state an equivalent form of Casas-Alvero conjecture.

**Conjecture 2.** *Let* $P(x)$ *a polynomial of degree* $1<n$ *and leading coefficient* $a_n\neq 0$. *The Casas-Alvero conjecture is equivalent to that the equation* $$P(x)\cdot\left(P^{(l+1)}(x)\right)^n=a_n\left((n-1)P^{(l)}(x)\right)^n,\tag{2}$$
*holds for each integer* $0\leq l<n-1$.

> **Question (Updated, considering the kindly advice of moderator in comments).** I would like to know **what work can be done** about the veracity of Conjecture 1, can you prove or refute Conjecture 1? **Many thanks.**

I don't know if these conjectures Conjecture 1 and Conjecture 2 are in the literature, my idea was very simple: that is to study the logarithmic derivative of derivatives of a given polynomial of the cited form, if it is in the literature please refer it in a comment or in your answer and I try to search and study this from the corresponding articles.

Remark: recently a professor solve a related question  [1].

### References:

[1] *Iterated derivatives and polynomials that are the power of a linear polynomial*, Mathematics Stack Exchange (Sep 12, 2021), post with identificator MSE [**4248459**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4248459/iterated-derivatives-and-polynomials-that-are-the-power-of-a-linear-polynomial)

Comment: I hope that the post is interesting, if the proof for Conjecture 1 is similar than provided the professor in his answer, just add suitable remarks to take a proof.

Comment: I hope that these conjectures are interesting, please add your feedback in comments. Also if you have some idea to improve the mathematical content of my conjectures. Many thanks

Comment: The way this question is phrased is quite broad -- you're basically asking "Is my conjecture true?". It almost sounds like you're asking somebody to write a grant proposal for you. The post could be improved if you stated more clearly the evidence you have for your conjecture(s) and why you think they are related to each other and to the Casas-Alvero conjecture. But most importantly, you should ask a more narrow, focused question. If you want general advice on how to do mathematical research, that's one thing. Otherwise, it should be more specific.

Comment: @TimCampion I was suspended an hour ago for 365 days in Meta Stack Exchange. Sure that you're right in which you are telling with your advices about how I can to improve my post and research (I'm not a professional), but what is the meaning of "It almost sounds like you're asking somebody to write a grant proposal for you." from a moderator? There is a lot of suffering behind the idea to ask of somedody for a grant or help. **For example, to be more specific** the first week of September asked to me two persons for money (one and two euros) because they need go to the hospital.

Comment: I'm referring to the notion of a [grant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funding_of_science) in the context of science funding. The point is that the way the question is phrased asks a lot of the answer-er. A good MathOverflow question does its best to make things easy on the answer-er by focusing as narrowly as possible on a concise, to-the-point question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm probably making a stupid mistake, but is Conjecture 1 possibly rather easy? At $\ell=0$ we're assuming

$$ p(x) = \frac{a_n}{n!} \left( \frac{n}{\frac{d}{dx} \log p(x)} \right)^n $$

Write $\frac{d}{dx} \log p(x) = \dfrac{q(x)}{r(x)}$, a reduced rational expression. Then the right hand side of the hypothesis is

$$ \frac{a_n}{n!} \left( \frac{n r(x)}{q(x)} \right)^n, $$

still a reduced rational expression, and this is equal to $p(x)$, a polynomial. So $q(x)$ is a constant.

Factor $p(x) = \frac{a_n}{n!} (x-r_1)^{e_1} \dotsm (x-r_k)^{e_k}$ (with all $e_i > 0$ and $r_i$ pairwise distinct). Then the logarithmic derivative is

$$ \frac{q(x)}{r(x)} = \frac{d}{dx} \log p(x) = \sum \frac{e_i}{x-r_i} . $$

The numerator of this sum is

$$ \sum_{i=1}^k e_i \prod_{j \neq i} x-r_j . $$

This is a nonzero polynomial (leading coefficient $\sum e_i = n = \deg p$) of degree $k-1$ (the number of distinct roots of $p$) and it's easy to see that its value at each $r_i$ is nonzero, so there will be no cancellation with the denominator. So, this is $q(x)$. It must be that this is constant. So the number of distinct roots of $p$ must be $k=1$, $p$ is a $k$th power.

This was only using the hypothesis at $\ell=0$, not all $0 \leq \ell < n-1$, so perhaps you can tell me if I've made some silly error or misunderstanding.

Comment: (I assumed that $\sum e_i = n = \deg p$ is not divisible by the characteristic of the field.)

Comment: Sure that if there is some lack here is from my side. As soon I can I study your excellent answer, many thanks. Feel free to study the veracity of Conjecture 2.

Comment: Conjecture 2: the condition (2) , for any single value of $\ell$, implies $P$ is an $n$th power, by unique factorization of polynomials. This is an immediate implication; it is not equivalent to the Casas-Alvero conjecture.

Comment: Perfect, many thanks I'm going to accept your answer, and after to study it when I can (I have not internet at home). Many thanks again for these resulsts. I see that your answers are elaborated maybe it is easy to you, but it is worthy.